# How to sort a fetch in Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

I'm doing a fetch of data to show it in a UITableView, I do the fetch but I want to sort them by date of creation or by any sort method.

Here is the method:

```
-(NSArray *) lesStations {

NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate]managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity =  [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Station" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

[fetch setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;

NSArray *result = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

if (!result) {
    return nil;
}

return result;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
-(NSArray *) lesStations {

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate]managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity =  [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Station" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    [fetch setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;

    NSArray *result = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

    if (!result) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:"creationDate" ascending:YES];



    NSArray *sortedResults = [result sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [sort release];

    return sortedResults;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options: get the results sorted or sort the `NSArray` with the results:
`NSFetchRequest` could be set a `NSArray` of `NSSortDescriptor`

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"place" ascending:NO]; //the key is the attribute you want to sort by
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

You can also sort the returned `NSArray` (see all instance methods of `NSArray` starting with `sortedArray...`)
I suggest using the first approach when working with CoreData. The second one is just informative when working with arrays...

Answer (score 0):

You can sort fetch results by setting sortDescriptors for fetch, e.g.

```
fetch.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: ascending: selector:], nil];
NSError *error;
NSArray *result = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
```