# Inserting NSManagedObject at begining of managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Im very new in CoreData framework.
Assume i have:

```
var textObjects = [NSManagedObject]()
```

then i populate it with some objects, for example:

`entity = ...,context = ...
for i in 0...2 {
  let textObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
  textObject.setValue("\(i)", forKey: "text"enter code here)
}`

After fetching i have array like `["0", "1", "2"]`.
Its like appending the Elements to the basic Array by function `.append(newElement:)`.
But i want behavior like function `.insert(newElement:,atIndex: 0)` so that i will have the array like `["2", "1", "0"]` (last inserted is always first).

Comment: Thanks to all! But i found the similar problem [here with answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052074/how-to-sort-a-fetch-in-core-data).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add a sort descriptor to your fetch request if you want to control the order in which the results are returned.
[NSSortDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons objects inserted in `NSManagedObjectContext` are always unordered.

Fetch the objects passing your favorite sort order in the `NSFetchRequest`